# MS SQL Server UPDATE FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql-server

Hello I'm trying to update data on my table with a FK constraint.
So I have this 2 tables.

[image]

I'm trying to UPDATE the PID 1 and Set it's ProductName to Burger and change its CID to 2 based on the CategoryName which is Food.

This what I tried so far,

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS 
   SET PRODUCTS.ProductName = 'Burger ', 
   PRODUCTS.CID = CATEGORY.CID
   FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON PRODUCTS.CID = CATEGORY.CID
   WHERE PID = '1' AND CATEGORY.CategoryName = 'Food';
```

It works but it didn't update the rows. Any idea what I missed? Thank you so much.

Comment: `WHERE PID = '1' AND CATEGORY.CategoryName = 'Food';` ...there are no rows in your table which match this criteria. You'd have to change the CID separately first before it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cid` in `products` currently isn't `2` so the joined `categoryname` isn't `'Food'` hence the `WHERE` clause doesn't match.

I'd simply use a subquery here.

```
UPDATE products
       SET productname = 'Burger',
           cid = (SELECT cid
                         FROM category
                         WHERE categoryname = 'Food')

       WHERE pid = 1;
```